# WooCommerce Change Email Recipient Depending on Shipping Country

Tags: php, wordpress, email, woocommerce

I am trying to dynamically add certain emails to the new order recipients list based on the customers ship-to address.

we are using PayPal advanced to process payments from within our site via n iframe.

The problem is that the filter that switches the email uses the customer's ship-to address which I am getting from one of two places:

`$woocommerce->customer->shipping_country`

`$woocommerce->session->customer['shipping_country'];`

Locally I don't have paypal advanced activated, so when test there it will work. However on the production server we are using it, and that's where the issue occurs. Those global objects are empty when the filter attempts to grab the customer's shipment order. This leads me to believe that once the PayPal order is done, the current page is redirected to the thank-you page with the proper information contained within it, however the global variables are empty when the filters are run.

With that said, how do I fetch the customer's shipping address info when `woocommerce_email_recipient_new_order` runs?

Comment: Can you show your filter code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Once the order is placed you need to retrieve information (such as shipping country) from the `$order` object and not from the session. The order is passed to the `woocommerce_email_recipient_new_order` filter [here](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/481471a64cccc97ffd084166f17ecf399dbd4ff3/includes/emails/class-wc-email.php#L269) as the second argument.

Here's an example of how you would pass the order object to your filter's callback and use it to modify the recipient:

```
function so_39779506_filter_recipient( $recipient, $order ){

    // get the shipping country. $order->get_shipping_country() will be introduced in WC2.7. $order->shipping_country is backcompatible
    $shipping_country = method_exists( $order, 'get_shipping_country') ) ? $order->get_shipping_country() : $order->shipping_country;

    if( $shipping_country == 'US' ){

        // Use this to completely replace the recipient.
        $recipient = 'stack@example.com';

        // Use this instead IF you wish to ADD this email to the default recipient.
        //$recipient .= ', stack@example.com';
    }
    return $recipient;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_new_order', 'so_39779506_filter_recipient', 10, 2 );
```

Edited to make code compatible with both WooCommerce 2.7 and previous versions.

Comment: Your answer is the one that led me to the solution, though this is what works:
`$order->shipping_country`, not the function. I didn't see a function like that in the API docs. Further, I didn't know that you can pass WC objects into action functions like that. Very cool!

Comment: Sorry, I think that's coming in WC 2.7. You can see it in the [source](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/class-wc-order.php#L719). Getting object properties directly will be deprecated, so keep that in mind for when you upgrade.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Though now I am left wondering if I should have `$recipient -= ', stack@example.com`; instead, as at least in the 2.7 code I'm working on the filter seems to expect a comma-delimited string of email addresses? Is that your understanding too?

Comment: @LoicTheAztec thanks for that! I've added it into the answer via comments for completion. And yes, WC2.7 will be backcompatible, but if you have debug mode on there will be an explosion of PHP warnings. I'm working on updating my plugins to be compatible and it's a hot mess.

Comment: @helgatheviking It's a hot mess for all the community then! That is not very smart from WC dev teams.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec it is indeed. I think 2.7 has added an incredible amount of complexity to it's code base and I'm not yet sure of the benefits.

Comment: @helgatheviking Yes you are right, this is the **Trump revolution in WC code**  :) … If you need some help, I could be more available on Monday I think… **This is going to be a real nightmare for the community.** They should introduce new methods, keeping old code behaviors without deprecate them in WC 2.7 … They should do that progressively. So with all  WooThemes plugins they have also a tremendous work before this update (I am just laughing thinking about it). May be this is the first real result of **Automatic** acquisition…